# Why do the tests for playframework fail with version 2.1.0?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to follow along with the tutorial on the [play framework](http://www.playframework.com/) but the tests fail when I get to the section where they run the tests. When I look at the error in my browser, it says that it can't find the index view. I'm not sure why that is. I'm guessing that they are using an older version in the video tutorial that is n their website.

If you know why the latest version (2.1.0) breaks, can you explain it to me please?

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;


public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Hello World."));
    }

}
```

This is the file that is causing the test to fail. When I look in IntelliJ the error says "Cannot resolve symbol index".

```
@Test
public void renderTemplate() {
    Content html = views.html.index.render("Hello World.");
    assertThat(contentType(html)).isEqualTo("text/html");
    assertThat(contentAsString(html)).contains("Your new application is ready.");
}
```

This is the code that is in the index.scala.html file

```
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play 2.1") {

    @play20.welcome(message, style = "Java")

}
```

This is the test that is failing. If I get rid of the index like this
    return ok("Hello World.");
and make the appropriate adjustment to the test, things will pass. But I'd like to know why they were failing in the first place. Especially since everything pretty much came right out of the box. Also, things run without an error. I can see the index page when I start the server, but for some reason when I try to run the tests I'm told that the test can't see the index file.

Comment: I think this might be a bug 2.1.0 that is being fixed for 2.1.1.  Can you provide the test code that is failing and the error or failure reason?

Comment: @JamesWard The test is failing because of the index.scala.html file.

Comment: @JamesWard I added the code from the file and the test that was causing things to fail.

Comment: Did you change your `index.scala.html`? If it still has the welcome message, it should work, since [the html does contain](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/play20/welcome.scala.html#L189) "Your new application is ready."

Comment: The IntelliJ error is due to the template not being compiled to a class yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the tutorial.  The test seems to be looking for the wrong string.  Try to change the last asset to:

```
assertThat(contentAsString(html)).contains("Hello World.");
```